# Получения параметров из ссылки

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

От удаленного сервера к моему приходит зарос с `url` вида:

```
http://mysite.ru/callback/#param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Поскольку это не параметры запроса, то я не понимаю как мне извлечь данные из урла. Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Разбор регулярным выражением.

Comment: Неужели нет более простых решений?

Comment: это и есть наиболее простое решение!)

Comment: http://javascript.ru/window-location

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать такой вариант:

```js
const url = "http://mysite.ru/callback/#param1=value1&param2=value2";
const queryParamsValue = url.split('#')[1].split('&').map(x => x.split('='));

console.log(queryParamsValue);
```

P.S. Я только не уверен на счёт знака `#` в запросе, мне кажется что там должно быть `?`